# "Super" key is not working

Tags: keyboard

Installed Ubuntu 17.10 and "Super" key is not working. It is not important for me, but I can't change languages. How I can find an alternative?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? If you run `xev`, nothing is logged in the terminal when you press the Super key?

Comment: @janos, nothing

Comment: Are you able to open Dash, using Super key?

Comment: Yes, using console

Comment: Intall `compizconfig-settings-manager` and under Unity Plugin, "Launcher" tab , check if your Super key is unset.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the **Language switch** hotkey in the **Settings**.